# Why does Ctrl-ScrollLock send message in GMail

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

I was writing a message in Gmail, and accidentally hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ScrollLock</kbd> on my keyboard. To my surprise, it sent my message. (I quickly pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo, thanks Gmail.)

I'm just curious: Why on earth would Gmail bind to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ScrollLock</kbd>? Who even knows that this key exists besides tech nerds? Many laptops don't even have it on their keyboards.